# Setting openssh port in windows for msysgit

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

A quick question. I am using msysgit with openSSH as a git client. i don't want to use other ssh clients such as putty. From GIT Bash I have succesfully connected to my server with ssh -p XXXX to my sever.

Unfortunately when i try to do something like:

```
git clone git@SERVER:reponame.git
```

from the Git Bash I get:

```
ssh: connect to host SERVER port 22 failed.
```

How can I make the ssh connection that msysgit tries to open with openssh run at a different port?

I know that in linux such a thing would be in /etc/ssh/ssh_config file but how would I go about doing that in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

git supports the following syntax for `ssh://`

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
```

Note the port in there.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply alex. If I try: git clone user@host:port/pathtorepo.git I still get the port 22 error. I am working on Git Bash

Comment: @lefteris, try `git clone ssh://user@host:port/pathtorepo.git`

Comment: thanks alex! That worked!!!!! It works through tortoise-git too. Finally setting up git is finished. A big thumbs up man :)